# Android GCM get send notification result from multiple device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notification to several devices, and I can do it by using this post data:

```
{
  "registration_ids" : 
  ["id_1",   "id_2",  "id_3"],
  "data" :{
    "messageContent": "Good Morning People!"
  }
}
```

But the problem is, how can I know the result for each device, because what I get is the result for the whole post data. In this example, I got success 3.

```
{
    "multicast_id": 0000xxxx123123,
    "success": 3,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:540728299xxxxxxxasdasdasdasdasdas"
        },
        {
            "message_id": "0:540728299xxxxxxxasdasdasdasdasdas"
        },
        {           
            "message_id": "0:540728299xxxxxxxasdasdasdasdasdas"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I got success 2 and failure 1, how can I know which device is failed to be sent?

Answer (score 0):

Each elements in *results* should be in the order of registration-IDs that you sent to GCM.

***results***

```
Array of objects representing the status of the messages processed. The objects are listed in the same order as the request (i.e., for each registration ID in the request, its result is listed in the same index in the response) and they can have these fields:
message_id: String representing the message when it was successfully processed.
registration_id: If set, means that GCM processed the message but it has another canonical registration ID for that device, so sender should replace the IDs on future requests (otherwise they might be rejected). This field is never set if there is an error in the request.
error: String describing an error that occurred while processing the message for that recipient. The possible values are the same as documented in the above table, plus "Unavailable" (meaning GCM servers were busy and could not process the message for that particular recipient, so it could be retried).
```

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html